# Dynamically adding ID's to links inside nav element

Tags: jquery, css, dynamically-generated

I am using Superslides, it is a jQuery fullscreen slider basically. It generates navigation links depending on the number of slides.

For my case I would need those navigation links absolutely positioned on different positions on screen. Here is the code it creates for the navigation:

```
<nav class="slides-pagination">
<a class="" href="#0"></a>
<a class="" href="#1"></a>
<a class="" href="#2"></a>
 <a class="current" href="#3"></a>
</nav>
```

My question is how can I add ID's to links, so I can position each one where I want. Or can I use the "href" attribute somehow to select them with jQuery, because each one has a different href?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can select them using jquery and href-property:

```
$('a[href="#1"]').css(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select links using href like:

```
$('.slides-pagination a[href="#0"]')  // Get the first link
$('.slides-pagination a[href="#1"]')  // Get the second link
```

Similarly you can get any link you want with a specific href using the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute selector as other answers suggest, in case that you want to add IDs, you can use `prop`perty or `attr`ibute method:

```
$('.slides-pagination a').prop('id', function(index) {
   return 'id' + index; // adding IDs based on the index of selected element 
});
```

Comment: It should be `$('.slides-pagination a')` instead of `$('.slides-pagination')`, since OP wants to _add ID's to links_